# Cannot send data using form from index.php

Tags: php, mysqli

I've run in to a small problem and I hope someone can help me out.

I made a form and it works fine:

http://www.volunteeringnews.com/formorg.php

If I hit send it returns a message saying User has been created.

So that works but if I go to http://www.volunteeringnews.com/ and under "Organisations" I click Submit it doens't work. And the Submit button is justa link to formorg.php.

I tried adding this to index.php but that was no success.

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

//include database connection
include 'mysqli.php';
```

Can someone have a look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $_POST variable will be filled with the form data passed to it.

So on your form you'll have something like this:

```
<form action="http://www.volunteeringnews.com/formorg.php" method="post">
<input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname'>
<input type='submit'>
```

Then when you submit that form, formorg.php will have the $_POST array populated with the names you gave the form fields. So, for example, to access whatever value the user filled out for the firstname field you'd access $_POST['firstname']

Comment: Thank you for your answer but using this will get me separated from my main page and I want to stay on it. I'll try ajax see what I can do there, thank you and Marcel very much for your answer though!

Comment: @RoaldVanDerTempel You can make the form action URL blank to submit to the current page, then you can do a check on the current page to see if $_POST is empty or not to process form data.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can see is that the Action is not correct.

Normaly you should set the Action to the Script you were wanting the Post data to be:

```
<form action="http://www.volunteeringnews.com/formorg.php" method="post" border="0">
```

Otherwise you are going to direct the Post to the index.php were you are not getting the Request Values.